# Mercury Editor save images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, mercury-editor

I used Mercury Editor for my Rails 3 website, but i have a litte problem with the uploaded images.
I have a image tag with data-mercury="image":

```
<img id="page_image" data-mercury="image" >
```

Then I set Mercury to send the data via a form to my controller. What I want to do is to store the image's url in the database.
How do I get the data sent by Mercury Editor ?

Normally when I have a div with data-mercury="full", I get the content in my controller like that:

```
params[:content][:page_content][:value]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resoved the problem with the following code:

```
#body

<img id="mercury_image" data-mercury="image" src="">
<div id="article_image" data-mercury="full"></div>

#jQuery

$(function() {
    $('#article_image').hide() ;
    $("#mercury_image").load(function(){ 
        $('#article_image').html($('#mercury_image').attr('src'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please expand on how you solved this and what you achieved?

Answer (score 0):

as I check the mercury demo , it saved the pictures url. So ,probably you can parse the content and capture the image url by using regular expression. Maybe you can use nokogiri as well to parse the html.

[Rails Cast Source](http://railscasts.com/episodes/296-mercury-editor)

[Official Mercury docmentation](http://jejacks0n.github.io/mercury/documentation/)

Comment: but it should have something like > params[:content][:page_image][:url] no ?

Comment: I saw the documentation and has no list this option, so probably you have to use page.content = params[:content][:page_content][:value] and parse to get the url. I update some reference that you can take a look into

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I can do it with a data-mercury="full", and have the content like usual, but I want to to take advantage of the data-mercury="image". That makes a fix area where you can only drag&drop an image.